# Hide cursor over image while using QueryCursor event in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an image in my application and I need to draw a line according to the mouse position. What I tried to do is use QueryCursor event to get the mouse position  and draw the line, which works as planned.
However, now I wish to hide the cursor while over the image so that only the line is visible. I tried to change the cursor to 'None' but then the event stopped working. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to set the `Cursor` property to `Cursors.None` in the `QueryCursor` event handler and then set it back to `null` when the `MouseLeave` event fires.

This works fine for me:

```
<Image ... QueryCursor="Button_QueryCursor" MouseLeave="Button_MouseLeave" />
```

---

```
private void Image_QueryCursor(object sender, QueryCursorEventArgs e)
{
    Cursor = Cursors.None;
    //...
}

private void Image_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Cursor = null;
}
```

Comment: It works but sometimes the cursor sort of flickers when moving over the image

Answer (score 0):

Please set the Cursors.None to the Windows' Cursor property

i.e  this.Cursor = Cursors.None;

Hope this helps.

Comment: After rechecking, this hides the cursor in the entire window while I wish to hide it only on the image